# ASP.NET Page Load - Cannot find control in edit item template

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Why I cannot find textbox control in edit item template in gridview?
I set Session["index"] on Edit button click

```
if (Session["index"] != null)  
{  TextBox txt =
     GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["index"])].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox; 

  txt.Text = "AAAAA";
}
```

GridView: http://pastebin.com/CwAqs2J3

Comment: because in the code that you give there is not `txtPhone` !!!

Comment: My bad. I tried several variants to achieve goal. I'm looking for txtEmail. Sorry

Comment: ok, where is the corect code?, and this is usually after you press edit. This is not the usual way to capture an edit... can you find some tutorial that says how ? Session is also bad design to use to find your editor

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
                    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

                    int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
                    Session["index"] = RowIndex.ToString();
                }
                
            }

Comment: this is how i forward row index to page load. Every time I get null - it cannot find control

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put it first into the object then determine if the control is a textbox something like this:

```
Textbox txt = new Textbox();
if(Session["index"] != null) {
    int sessionIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["index"]);
    object thiscontrol = GridView1.rows[sessionIndex].FindControl("txtPhone");
    if(thiscontrol is typeof(Textbox))
    {
        txt = thiscontrol;
        txt.Text = "AAAAA";
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. I still getting null